# where is block stored in hyperledger fabric V1.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I just new with Hyperledger, so when I tried to run fabcar, first-network sample application as tutorial in link [Writing Your First Application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/write_first_app.html)

I also read about block concept in Hyperledger at this link 
[Ledger](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/ledger/ledger.html)

Now I want to see detail information of the block data such as: block header, block number, current hash block, previous hash block...

I had tried access couchdb but not found the data of block in chains.

Can anybody help me how to access block data.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to view the block data is using [Hyperledger Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/tree/master).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will try to use Hyperledger explorer as you suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB acts as the stateDB, that means it only saves the current state of a value, and *not* all transactions on that value. For example, there are 10 transactions in a bank account----the stateDB only saves the current balance, and the actual blockchain saves all 10 transaction.

To look at actual blocks in the blockchain, one option is to use [Query System Chaincode (QSCC)](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/chaincode4noah.html?highlight=qscc), or if you are ok with non-fabric ways, Hyperledger explorer as Paul suggested.